# Code not cycling through to the last cell which needs updating

Tags: vba, excel

I have several text items that need to change.  The data that needs to change will only appear in Column B of the spreadsheet.  The code works but in a long list, the last occurrence of a valid change does not happen. For ex. "Roger" is not updated when it is the last populated cell and needs to change.  In reality I have about 12 of the IF Then statements.

I tried inserting loop and received an error.

```
Sub Names2()
Dim aRow As Integer

For aRow = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(2))

    If Cells(aRow, 2) = "Jay" Then
       Cells(aRow, 2) = "Jason"
    End If

    If Cells(aRow, 2) = "Steve" Then
       Cells(aRow, 2) = "Steven"
    End If

    If Cells(aRow, 2) = "Rog" Then
       Cells(aRow, 2) = "Roger"
    End If

    Next aRow

End Sub
```

Comment: You never declare what aRow is. You could also easily solve this issue with index/match as well

Comment: Thank you, Doug.  I omitted that, in error, when I pasted above.  I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also You can do this without Looping (faster):

```
Sub test()

 With Columns("B")
  .Replace "Jay", "Jason", xlWhole
  .Replace "Steve", "Steven", xlWhole
  .Replace "Rog", "Roger", xlWhole
 End With

End Sub
```

To use `Select Case` (for column "A"):

```
 Select Case Cells(aRow, 1).Value
  Case "Jay"
   Cells(aRow, 1).Value = "Jason"
  Case "Steve"
   Cells(aRow, 1).Value = "Steven"
  Case "Rog"
   Cells(aRow, 1).Value = "Roger"
 End Select
```

Comment: Thank you, Fadi. I am going to try this now.  It is much more straight forward.

Comment: @Rblossom, You are welcome. and if you want to use your code try to use `Select Case` it will be faster than 3 `If...Then statement`.

Comment: Works great.  Thank you.

Comment: Would you please give me an example of how I can substitute Select Case in my code?

Comment: Thank you, again.  This is great information @Fadi!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Sub Names2()
Dim aRow As Long, FRowB As Long
Dim wk As Worksheet
Dim m As Long

Set wk=Sheet1         'Replace this with your Worksheet Number

m=wk.Rows.Count

FRowB = wk.Range("B" & m).End(xlUp).Row

For aRow = 1 To FRowB

    If Cells(aRow, 2) = "Jay" Then Cells(aRow, 2) = "Jason"

    If Cells(aRow, 2) = "Steve" Then Cells(aRow, 2) = "Steven"

    If Cells(aRow, 2) = "Rog" Then Cells(aRow, 2) = "Roger"


Next aRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Rohan K.  This works great.  One question, if I have to replicate this for use in another column, as in A, for example, what all should change?

Comment: Dim aRow As Long, FRowB As Long
Dim wk As Worksheet
Dim m As Long

Set wk=Sheet1        

m=wk.Rows.Count

FRowB = wk.Range("A" & m).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Change this `FRowB = wk.Range("B" & m).End(xlUp).Row` to `FRowB = wk.Range("A" & m).End(xlUp).Row` and this `If Cells(aRow, 2) = "Jay" Then Cells(aRow, 2) = "Jason"` to `If Cells(aRow, 1) = "Jay" Then Cells(aRow, 1) = "Jason"`

Comment: Thank you, again, Rohan.

Answer (score 1):

Thevalue of arow is 1 all over the code, you need to increment it to move it to next row, to make it easier for you to understand I am not writing a new code for the task but modifying your code

```
Sub Names2()

For aRow = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(2))

If Cells(aRow, 2) = "Jay" Then
   Cells(aRow, 2) = "Jason"
aRow = aRow+1
End If

If Cells(aRow, 2) = "Steve" Then
   Cells(aRow, 2) = "Steven"
aRow = aRow+1
End If

If Cells(aRow, 2) = "Rog" Then
   Cells(aRow, 2) = "Roger"
aRow = aRow+1
End If

Next aRow

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this, as well.

Comment: The syntax is Cells(row,column) .... To move it to any other column you just need to change column number `Cells(aRow,1)` for A....`Cells(aRow,3)` for C...`Cells(aRow,4)` for D... and so on..Thanks

Comment: This code didn't actually work for me but I thank you for the input.

Comment: yeah this may not work because I didnt checked it on my VBA sorry I am on my phone right now

Comment: No worries.  Thank you, again, for your input.